# C# How to do on-the-fly compression-and-send in a API controller to avoid large memory buffers

Tags: c#, api, pipe, compression, .net-6.0

What I am trying to achive is to send a backup (stream) from the API to the requestor, and in the process avoid taking up large amounts of RAM. I have been experimenting using `Pipes`, but didnt get it to work (probably lack of knowledge ;) )

Take a look at the following routine:

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("{projectIdentifier}")]
        [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> BackupProject(string projectIdentifier, bool zipped = false)
        {
            if (!TryGetProject(projectIdentifier, out var project))
                return this.NotFoundResult(nameof(projectIdentifier), projectIdentifier);

            string filenamePartName = $"Project {project.Identifier}";
            string saveFilename = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(filenamePartName, (current, c) => current.Replace(c, '_'));

            MemoryStream backupstream = new();
            await Core.Iapetus.Instance.Projects.BackupAsync(backupstream, project.ID, zipped); 
            backupstream.Position = 0;
            var file = zipped ? File(backupstream, "application/zip", $"{saveFilename}.json.gz") : File(backupstream, "application/json", $"{saveFilename}.json");
            return file;
        }
```

The BackupAsync routine supports compression using the `GZipSTream` class, and this works on-the fly. Unfortunately the compressed (or not) result still lands in the `backupstream` memory buffer taking up way much more space than I like in some cases.

**The question**

Is there a way to "skip" the memory buffer, and send the data directly from the (compressed) stream to  the `File` response? And -off course- keeping the whole shabang `async`

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a streaming file result type in ASP.NET, but they do provide the support to define your own.

You can use a streaming file result type similar to the one [on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html), updated for ASP.NET 6:

```
public sealed class FileCallbackResult : FileResult
{
    private readonly Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> _callback;

    public FileCallbackResult(MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, Func<Stream, ActionContext, Task> callback)
        : base(contentType.ToString())
    {
        _ = callback ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callback));
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        var executor = new FileCallbackResultExecutor(context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>());
        return executor.ExecuteAsync(context, this);
    }

    private sealed class FileCallbackResultExecutor : FileResultExecutorBase
    {
        public FileCallbackResultExecutor(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            : base(CreateLogger<FileCallbackResultExecutor>(loggerFactory))
        {
        }

        public Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, FileCallbackResult result)
        {
            SetHeadersAndLog(context, result, fileLength: null, enableRangeProcessing: false);
            return result._callback(context.HttpContext.Response.Body, context);
        }
    }
}
```

It's used like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{projectIdentifier}")]
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public IActionResult BackupProject(string projectIdentifier, bool zipped = false)
{
  if (!TryGetProject(projectIdentifier, out var project))
    return this.NotFoundResult(nameof(projectIdentifier), projectIdentifier);

  string filenamePartName = $"Project {project.Identifier}";
  string saveFilename = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(filenamePartName, (current, c) => current.Replace(c, '_'));

  return new FileCallbackResult(
      new MediaTypeHeaderValue(zipped ? "application/zip" : "application/json"),
      async (outputStream, _) =>
      {
        await Core.Iapetus.Instance.Projects.BackupAsync(outputStream, project.ID, zipped);
      })
  {
    FileDownloadName = zipped ? $"{saveFilename}.json.gz" : $"{saveFilename}.json",
  };
}
```

A word of warning (also noted [on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html)): error handling is now more awkward. Previously, if `BackupAsync` threw an exception, you would return an error code to the client. Now that you're streaming the result, the headers (including `200 OK`) have *already been sent*, so if `BackupAsync` throws an exception, the only way ASP.NET has to notify the client is to just terminate the connection, and different browsers may interpret that differently. I believe most browsers will correctly say "download error" or some such generic message, but it is possible that the user will just end up with a truncated file in that case.

Comment: This look very useful, I'll try if asap! Another solution I thought about is storing the intermediate result not in memory but in a temp file, and download it from there. This saves RAM, and sind downloads are more or "slow" it wouldnt mke much of a performance difference. But then again I might get stuck with a gazillion temp files if something breaks :s

Comment: There are two benefits to the temp file solution: 1) your code can send a `Content-Length` header (since it knows the length before the content is sent), and can possibly also handle range requests if necessary; and 2) error handling becomes nicer: since `BackupAsync` completes before sending the response code, your code can pass along error info. The drawback, as you noted, is that you now have temp files. You'll need to handle cleanup (even in the case of crashes), naming conflicts, etc.

Comment: Update: the [sample code here](https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/AsyncDynamicZip/tree/net6-ziparchive) now has a working ASP.NET Core 6 implementation.